# Raspberry PI Login via python if true starts an event

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a Python script that will simply be created in Nano then place it under my startup script file, so when I turn on the raspberry pi the user will type in a password and if that's "True" it will start other devices to work.

I have not created the login script (Yet) since i know how to create it, but my pseudo code looks similar to this...:

```
[...]
#Login script
 if session == True: 
                     sudo python greenledflash.py

Else:
   if session == False:
            sudo python redledflash.py
            sudo python login.py #Restarts python script
```

Not sure if this is possible, but im trying to make it so that if the user enters a correct password it will start an event, else it will start another event if the password is false.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Are you trying to launch something on log-in? Why not just use the standard OS methods of doing this?  Are you trying to prompt users to enter a secondary password (after login)?  There's so much missing from this that I can't even begin to answer it.

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 and using putty / SSH'ing into the raspberry pi. And i don't want to prompt users for a secondary password, i'm simply trying to create a login script, SSH that on the raspberry pi then connect a keyboard to it ..if the password is correct it will show up a green light otherwise a red light if it's wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify you want you want something to happen when users connect to your Rasperry Pi through SSH? It does not seem a very good idea to give users SSH access, simply to turn on a led or something (and besides SSH on windows is not very straightforward). Also, if the password is wrong your login script won't be executed. You should rather run a simple web server, see for instance flask (web server is included),  and do this password check when the user enters some url in a browser.

Comment: First, unless I'm mistaken, Windows 8.1 doesn't run on a Raspbery Pi (I believe it was limited to Galileo, maybe I'm wrong?).  Second, you're not creating a login script, because you want something to execute *before* login happens (otherwise, it'd never execute on failure).  This isn't so much a raspbery pi or python question, but an OS question.  You may want to just create a script to continously monitor your Raspberry Pi's SSH log script, and thread out your LED flashes based on the contents of new line entries.  Either way, I'd recommend re-thinking and clarifying this question.

Comment: Afaik windows8 does run on rasbperrypi2 ... I was wrong its windows10